# Define primitive recursive function

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

(it's not homework, this question is supposed to be supplementary material for students to understand the lecture material better!)

I have specific function that needs to be proved to be primitive recursive, however I have some difficulties on how to start tackling such problem.

Having $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined as the number of integer numbers that divide a natural number,
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{ when } n=0\\|\{a\in\Bbb N\mid\exists b\in\Bbb N: a*b=n\}|,&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

An example output would be $f(6)=4$ as $6$ is divisible by four integers $1,6,2,3$.

In order to define such function no LOOP/WHILE/GOTO programms are allowed.

Comment: Can we use the function smallestprimefactor(n) ? This would allow to formulate $f(n)$ recursively.

Comment: I think I would first need to define that smallestprimefactor(n) is primitive recursive

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235019/primitive-recursive-definition-of-the-divisibility-relation) show that the function $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x\text{ is divisible by }y\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ is primitive recursive, and you can combine it with the bounded summation mentioned in the second answer. You may also find [this PDF](http://courses.homelinux.org/general/recursive-function-theory.pdf), especially sections $5$ and $6$, helpful.

Comment: thank you, the question and pdf are very helpful!